# How to watch file changes on Mac OSX using FSWatch?

Tags: macos, sh, monitor, inotifywait, fswatch

I'm trying to use [fswatch](https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch) to translate the following lines from a linux bash script to be able to run it on Mac OSX:

```
inotifywait -r -m 'myfolder/' | while read MODFILE
do
    echo "something"
done
```

Since inotifywait doesn't work on Mac OSX I want to substitute the first line for [FSWatch](https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch). Although the README refers to the fswatch man page, it doesn't provide a link to it and a search around the internet doesn't get me anything. So I tried messing around a bit.

I created a folder called `testfswatch/` and I tried running the following commands in the parent folder and then adding and changing files on the `testfswatch/` folder:

```
fswatch -o testfswatch/ | echo "LALA"
fswatch -o testfswatch/ | someSimpleProgram
fswatch -o testfswatch/ | xargs -n1 -I{} echo "LALA"
fswatch -o testfswatch/ | xargs -n1 -I{} ./someExecutable
fswatch -o testfswatch/ | xargs -n1 echo "LALA"
fswatch -o testfswatch/ | xargs -n1 someExecutable
// And more variations of the above
```

None of these commands seem to do anything when I change or add files in the `tesfswatch/` folder though.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: @Bushmills - Ah ! was indeed on version `0.0.2`. I just upgraded to version `1.3.7`, and things seem to work now! Thanks a million! ps. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pre-1.0 versions of fswatch use a slightly different invocation syntax, compared to 1.0 and later.
Make sure that you're running a version later than 1.0, You may want to upgrade if your version is older than that.

Answer (score 20):

As already said by Bushmills, `fswatch` syntax has changed in v. >= 1.x after it was merged with `fsw`: the rationale behind this decision was allowing more than one path to be watched using a syntax that felt natural to UNIX users.

Furthermore, one specific option (`-0`) was added to allow easy and non-error-prone piping of `fswatch` output to another program's input:  when using `-0`, `fswatch` will separate records using the `NUL` (`\0`) character (along the lines of what other utilities such as `find` and `xargs` do).

In your case, then, you probably want to use the following syntax (fine tune it according to your needs):

```
$ fswatch -0 [opts] [paths] | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} [command]
```

This way:

- `fswatch -0` will split records using the `NUL` character.
- `xargs -0` will split records using the `NUL` character.  This is required to correctly match impedance with `fswatch`.
- `xargs -n 1` will invoke `command` every command.  If you want to do it every `x` records, then use `xargs -n x`.
- `xargs -I {}` will substitute occurrences of `{}` in `command` with the parsed argument.  If the command you're running does not need the event path name, just delete this option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do we watch for a specific filetype ?

Comment: I would use inclusion/exclusion filters. Their usage is documented in both the man page and the PDF documention here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxZtP9CHH-Q6bHF3bmJGRmlVcVU&usp=sharing. You would setup an exclusion filter to filter everything out with `-E ".*"` and then you would add an inclusion filter to add the pattern you want with `-Ie ".*\.js". However, you should ask a different question because this has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Just a quick note: I tried to use `-E ".*"` without success in version 1.4.7 of fswatch. Using `-e ".*"` with an inclusion filter works. E.g.: `fswatch -0 -e ".*" -i ".html" tmp/capybara/`

Comment: I'm sorry I mispelled the option there: `-e` specifies an exclusion filter, while `-E` tells `fswatch` to use extended regular expressions. Since inclusion filters always have the precedence on exclusion filters, no matter the order of the options, then what you are doing is correct: you exclude everything, but include files which match `.html`.  A suggestion: if you are interested in filtering `.html` as an extension, perhaps you'd rather use `.html$`.