# Stop watching a folder for changes if a file exists (bash)

Tags: bash, fswatch

I'm using `fswatch` to keep track of changes to a directory, but would like this process to stop if a certain file exists (with a wildcard). This certain file is created in an alternative directory (not in the tracked directory) by another process (which is generating changes that need to be tracked).

Here's what I tried to do:

```
while [[ $(shopt -s nullglob; set -- "${file_to_check}"; echo $#) -eq 1 ]]; do
   fswatch "${path_to_the_tracked_directory}"
done && echo "Done"
```

However, this script does not terminate after `${file_to_check}` appears.

The complex bit in the condition is to take care of wildcards as per: [Bash check if file exists with double bracket test and wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615535/bash-check-if-file-exists-with-double-bracket-test-and-wildcards)

EDIT:

The complex bit can be simplified to:

```
while [ $(set -- "${path_to_the_file_to_check}"${file_to_check_with_wildcards}; echo $#) -eq 0 ]; do
   fswatch "${path_to_the_tracked_directory}"
done && echo "Done"
```

Comment: You have transcribed the code incorrectly.  There needs to be a space after the `set --`

Comment: Also, double-quoting the pattern means you might as well simply use `while ! [ -f "$file_to_check" ]` -- the code you linkes to is for checking whether a wildcard matches exactly one file, as opposed to zero or several.  With a single static file name and no wildcard, that's obviously serious overkill.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks, actually my first try was `while [ ! -f "${file_to_check}" ]`, but it doesn't seem to work with wildcards.

Comment: If you want wildcards in `$file_to_check` you cannot use double quotes around it.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks, but my path contains spaces. If I put double quotes only around the part of the path that contains spaces, then I get `too many arguments` error (I guess due to multiple matches).

Comment: @econ: How are you detecting the file changes with `fswatch`, because the man page (http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/doc/1.5.0/html/fswatch/Tutorial-Introduction-to-fswatch.html) suggests using an option `fswatch -o <path>`  Refer this page http://stackoverflow.com/a/24574680/5291015 for more details.

Comment: As a workaround, perhaps split up the pattern into a wildcard part and a static part, and use `set -- $wildcard_part"$static_part"` -- I could find no sane way to quote a variable so that it can be evaluated without quotes and still contain some escaped metacharacters.

Comment: @Inian: Thanks, I'm actually using the same syntax as in MWE, just substituting the path of the directory.

Comment: @tripleee: Thank you, this simplifies the conditional, but `fswatch` still continues after `${file_to_check}` appears.

Comment: I found one possible solution, but I'm wary that there might be problems with this approach (or at least some inefficiencies), so not going to accept this as an answer just yet.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `-1/--one-event` option (https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/wiki/How-to-Use-fswatch).

The code then looks as:

```
while [ $(set -- "${path_to_the_file_to_check}"${file_to_check_with_wildcards}; echo $#) -eq 0 ]; do
      fswatch -1 "${path_to_the_tracked_directory}"
done && echo "Done"
```